# How to change hover color on bulk-action-selector-top and bottom on wordpress admin?

Tags: css

i want to change this hover color

[image]

i tried via css:

```
#bulk-action-selector-top{
color:#FFF;
}
```

but this not working.
How to change it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but there is no easy way to do it and no possible way with css.

Here is a similar thread in StackOverflow, that has the issue discussed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html